# TNS:Listener to JDBC Url

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, sql-loader, tns

I have a small program wrapping Oracles SQLLoader utility. The database address parameter SQLLoader takes seems to be a TNS style address like so:

```
username/password@schemaname
```

My program also uses JDBC to access the database and perform post load diagnostics. Unfortunately at the moment, you need to supply the address as well like so:

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:username/password@172.17.125.131:1521:EE
```

Is there anyway to convert to and from these? I.e. if given a JDBC url, convert to a TNS address SQLLoader will take, and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL*Loader connection is using a TNS alias (so `schemaname` is not quite right generically, but may happen to be true for you). Converting from that to something like the JDBC string would involve parsing the data out of the `tnsnames.ora` file, which is doable but not trivial (though I'm sure someone with better awk-fu than me would disagree). If you look in that file you should see an entry with address values corresponding to the JDBC values.

Going the other way is much simpler as you can use 'easy connect' syntax in your SQL*Loader command in place of the TNS alias:

```
sqlldr username/password@172.17.125.131:1521/EE control=...
```

As you can see, this is *almost* trivial to convert to (or from) a JDBC address, as you just have to add (or remove) the `jdbc:oracle:thin:` part. Except, the final delimiter changes from `/` to `:`. How you change that will depend on your wrapper program - whether it's a Windows batch file, a *nix shell script, a C executable etc. The simplest way may be to obtain the elements separately and concatenate them differently, but depends on how you're calling it too.

Answer (score 0):

You can create the required strings you need from the database once connected (and without been sysadmin).

Perhaps it seems foolish but to query the same parameters from any utility will take you very long time to program.

```
SELECT
  USER
  ||'/******@'
  || sys_context('userenv','db_name') as simpleconnection
  ,'jdbc:oracle:thin:'
      ||USER
      ||'/******@'
      || sys_context('userenv', 'server_host') --host
      || ':'
      || sys_context('USERENV', 'SID') --port
      || ':'
      || sys_context('userenv','db_name') AS "Oracle Eight" --SID
  ,'jdbc:oracle:thin:'
      ||USER
      ||'/******@'
      ||sys_context('userenv', 'server_host') --host
      ||':'
      ||sys_context('USERENV', 'SID') --port
      ||'/'
      ||  sys_context('userenv','service_name') AS "host form"
  ,'jdbc:oracle:thin:'
      ||USER
      ||'/******@'
      ||sys_context('userenv', 'ip_address')  --ip
      ||':'
      ||sys_context('USERENV', 'SID') --port
      ||'/'
      ||  sys_context('userenv','service_name') AS "IP form"
  ,'jdbc:oracle:thin:'
      ||USER
      ||'/******@(description=(address=(host='
      ||sys_context('userenv', 'server_host')    --host
      ||')(protocol='
      ||sys_context('userenv', 'network_protocol')  --protocol
      ||')(port='
      ||sys_context('USERENV', 'SID')  --port
      ||'))(connect_data=(service_name='
      ||  sys_context('userenv','service_name')  --service name
      ||')(server='
      ||sys_context('userenv','host')  --name of the machine
      ||')))' AS "TNS form"
FROM dual d;
```

btw it's not considered a good practice to put login credentials into the connection string because a lack of readibility, you can add them as parameters.